# css - unordered list with no hard returns

Tags: css, html-lists

How can I make unordered list (ul/li) not begin on a new line for each LI.
User wants the bullet, but to save space, not show bullet on each line.

Yes I know it is strange request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use:

```
li { display: inline; }
```

To remove the way that li's normally go on a new line. People have used that method in additional to style: none; for CSS based horizontal navigation for quite a while now.

Comment: Very true both of you, thirtydot's answer is what you're after, I forgot to read fully! sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

A better method, provided you don't need <IE7 support, would be: http://jsfiddle.net/csswizardry/8czmt/

It's better because display:inline is a lot more predictable than float:left, which would require you to use a clearfix or similar on the `<ul>`.

H

Answer (score 0):

With `float:left;` and a bit of margin/padding tweaking

http://jsfiddle.net/mrmikemccabe/TZqMy/

Answer (score 0):

you can also use:

```
li {float:left}
```

or

```
.ul_class_name li {float : left}
```

(in case you have more than one ul and want to do this only to this one.

Remember you have to make

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

after closing the ul if you choose this

Comment: yeah and you have to tweak the left padding/margins obviously

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
ul { overflow:hidden; list-style-type:none } //clear internal float and remove bullet
li { margin:0 5px; float:left; width:auto; } //ie6 additions are needed as width auto is problemativ

<ul>
  <li>content</li>
  <li>content</li>
  <li>content</li>
</ul>
```

I prefer using floats, but of course you can use display:inline as well...

Comment: The default value of `width` is `auto`, you never need to specify it unless you're overriding something else.

Comment: yep just making it clear that for IE6 auto widths wont render correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case all I needed was the below code:

```
style='margin-top: 1px;'
```